# Locus of focus of ellipse which touches the $x$-axis

Tags: conic-sections

An ellipse touches the $x$ axis. The length of the major axis is $2a$ while the minor axis is given as $2b$, What would be the locus of its focus? ($a>b$.)

**My Approach:**

If the foci are $(x_1,y_1$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, then $(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2 = 4(a^2 - b^2),$ also $y_1y_2 = b^2,$ since product of perpendicular subtended from the foci on any tangent is $b^2$.

These are the properties which seem relevant in this question but I am not able to use them to find out the answer. I also might be missing out on other things.

Any hints/solutions to the problem are appreciated.

Comment: In the standard equation of the ellipse, $a \gt b$ and $b^2 = a^2(1-e^2)$. So the relation b/w $a$ and $b$ is $a^2-b^2=a^2e^2$ where $e$ is the eccentricity and $0 < e <1$ Try these!

Comment: @Algebrology This is what I used to obtain $(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2 = 4(a^2 - b^2)$ is there anything else I can do with the property ?

Comment: Can you find the foci of this ellipse?

Comment: Not sure, getting confused because of x1,x2 which are both variable

Comment: The foci of the ellipse are $F_1(ae,0)$ and $F_2(-ae,0)$. Now I guess you can find the locus of the focus

Comment: @Algebrology How can you assume the major axis of the ellipse to be parallel to the x-axis? I don't think that should be right

Comment: Oh didn't read the question. I thought it was parallel to the x-axis

Comment: "Touches the $x$ axis" is too vague. Moreover, an ellipse has two foci. Are you sure the text of the question is correct?

Comment: From touches the x axis I infer that x axis is tangent to the ellipse. Yes the focii are two and its locii need's to be found. Language is the same as in the question

Comment: A focus can be at any position $(,)$ in the plane with the constraint $−≤≤+$
or $-−≤≤-+$, where $=\sqrt{^2−^2}$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca now that you've mentioned this I see it too. It is very vague then. The locus in the answer was given as $(xy^2 + b^2x)^2 + (y^2 - b^2)^2y^2 = 4(a^2 - b^2)y^4$ does it hind to some extra info which they failed to mention in the question?

Comment: Yes, that curve is the result if the ellipse touches the $x$ axis at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT.

The ellipse touches the $x$ axis at the origin (see comments to the question). Hence,
if $F_1=(x,y)$, then
$\displaystyle F_2=\left(-{b^2\over y^2}x, {b^2\over y}\right)$.

Insert these into $\overline{F_1F_2}^2=4(a^2-b^2)$ to get the desired relation.

[image]